# Reg sub repeated character not in order

Tags: regex

I want to get something like that:

Input: `'abcad121'`

Output: `'abcd12'`

I tried to use regex pattern `r'(.)(?=.*\1)'` but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with PyPi regex module that you can install using `pip install regex` and then use:

```py
import regex
print( regex.sub(r'(.)(?<=\1.*\1)', '', 'abcad121') )
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqugKDOvRAPC0SsuTdIoUtfQ09Swt7GNMdTTijHUVNdRUAfhxKTkxBRDI0N1TQXN//8B). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EFVsr9/1), too. The point here is to capture a char first, and then check if there is such a char some 0 or more chars immediately to the left of the char.

If you want to use `re`, you will need to reverse the string first, run your current regex, and then reverse the resulting string:

```py
import re
text = 'abcad121'
print( re.sub(r'(.)(?=.*\1)', '', text[::-1])[::-1] )
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/RXcoYW).